# How could I easily quantify the amount of EGCG in a sample of green tea?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I am currently conducting an experiment to study the effects of pH on the rate of thermal decomposition of Epigallocatechin Gallate (EGCG) in green tea.

One of the key steps in my procedure is quantifying this EGCG content in the green tea. What are some of the methods which I could use to determine and quantify this EGCG content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To analyze specifically this component, you will have to use HPLC. 
In case you can use a more generic approach, you can analyze the total phenolic content with the Folin-Ciocalteu method.

The Folin-Ciocalteu method is based on a reaction with polyphenols that gives a blue color. 
This color can then be measured in a UV-Vis spectrophotometer and the concentration can be established.

This method has been used to quantify polyphenols in many plants, as for example [here](http://www.mdpi.com/1420-3049/18/6/6852/pdf).

Comment: Can I get a more detailed breakdown of the Folin-Ciocalteu method? There isnt a HPLC in the lab im working in

Comment: It is based on a reagent for polyphenols and a UV-Vis spectrophotometer. But remember that it will give you the concentration of all the polyphenols not only ECGC. I shall edit to provide e reference

Comment: Thanks a lot. I read up on this method previously and one of the things I could not get my head around was the reason for the addition of Sodium Carbonate to the solution.

Comment: If it has been useful you might consider accepting the answer